# Syslog file of 168.5GB, keeps filling up with "Please type y to accept, n otherwise..."

Tags: syslog

My syslog file will fill up no matter what i delete.  It's up to 165GB now. i tailed it, and heres the output?? wow:

```
Please type y to accept, n otherwise: Please type y to accept, n otherwise:
Please type y to accept, n otherwise: Please type y to accept, n otherwise:
Please type y to accept, n otherwise: Please type y to accept, n otherwise:
Please type y to accept, n otherwise: Please type y to accept, n otherwise:
Please type y to accept, n otherwise: Please type y to accept, n otherwise:
Please type y
May 24 07:12:57 Pat-PC gnome-session[1651]: to accept, n otherwise:
Please type y to accept, n otherwise: Please type y to accept, n otherwise:
Please type y to accept, n otherwise: Please type y to accept, n otherwise:
Please type y to accept, n otherwise: Please type y to accept, n otherwise:
Please type y to accept, n otherwise: Please type y to accept, n otherwise:
Please type y to accept, n otherwise: Please type y to accept, n otherwise:
```

This is ridiculous. It keeps going.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've added a script or program to the startup process that issues the "`Please type y to accept, n otherwise:`" message, tries (and fails) to read a response, and prompts again. Investigate with `ps -ef` and `pstree -a -c -l -p -u 1651`. Kill the prompting process and fix your startup scripts.

Comment: ok. it seems to have stopped after killing 1651. it did break everything and i had to restart, but thats fine. also got the syslog cleared with   sudo cat /dev/null > /var/log/syslog    then tailed it again and it's doing normal things. thanks

Comment: You have just stopped the current problem. Unless you fix the cause, the problem will happen again when next you login.

Comment: Wrong. Just tailed it again. Logged in multiple times and heres the output:   May 25 21:22:25 Pat-PC nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlxe894f61479b0]: new request (1 scripts)
May 25 21:22:25 Pat-PC nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlxe894f61479b0]: start running ordered scripts...
May 25 21:22:25 Pat-PC dhclient[9955]: bound to 000.000.00.000 -- renewal in 255 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what the offending program is causing the endless loop use:

```
$ sudo time grep -rnw --exclude-dir={boot,dev,lib,media,mnt,proc,root,run,sys,/tmp,tmpfs,var} '/' -e 'Please type y to accept, n otherwise'Binary file /home/rick/.mozilla/firefox/3vkvi6ov.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4 matches
Binary file /home/rick/.mozilla/firefox/3vkvi6ov.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.baklz4 matches
Binary file /home/rick/.mozilla/firefox/3vkvi6ov.default/places.sqlite matches
Binary file /home/rick/.mozilla/firefox/3vkvi6ov.default/places.sqlite-wal matches
10.24user 11.60system 0:50.74elapsed 43%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 15268maxresident)k
16205768inputs+0outputs (0major+4553minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

I don't have the same problem so the three programs listed are not offenders.